# How to load new LARGE product data in excel into Hybris?

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud

It is in CSV format into SAP Hybris commerce suite. How to Create product description etc? What steps we need to take?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

**Steps:**

**1. Create an import impex for Product like this:**

```
$catalogVersion=catalogVersion(catalog(id[default=STORE-PRODUCTS]),version[default=Online])[unique=true]
$approvalStatus=approvalStatus(code)[default='approved']
$unit=unit(code)[default=pieces]

INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true,allownull=true];name[lang=en];ean;onlineDate[dateformat=yyyy/MM/dd];offlineDate[dateformat=yyyy/MM/dd];description[lang=ja];minOrderQuantity;galleryImages($catalogVersion,qualifier);picture($catalogVersion,code);thumbnail($catalogVersion,code);manufacturerAID;manufacturerName;variantType(code);$catalogVersion;$approvalStatus;$unit
```

Modify the impex as required.

**2. Add the entry for your csv file in impex as below:**

"#% impex.includeExternalDataMedia( ""Products.csv"" , ""UTF-8"", ';',  1 , -1 );"

**3. Zip this impex and csv file together.**

**4. Use the Import functionality in HMC to import the zipped file.**

Make sure your CSV file is changed to the format as required in impex.

**Solution 2:**

The other preferable solution is to use **Hot Folder** functionality of Hybris. For more details see [this](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/Hot+Folder)

**Solution 3:**

Use the **IBM MDM tool** to create an import profile and upload your csv data. Once your csv data is uploaded, you can create and export profile and export your data in impex file format. This impex can be imported into Hybris through HMC or HAC.

Hope this helps!